# Change to back camera in webview (Android)

Tags: android, webview, android-camera

I want do a application with HTML5 and include a take a photo system. I have just include a code to show a camera :

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                    KioskActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            request.grant(request.getResources());
                        }// run
                    });// MainActivity
                }// onPermissionRequest
            });// setWebChromeClient
```

But always show a frontal camera and i need a back camera. Can you help me, please? Thx. :)

Comment: Sorry as I don't have an answer to your question. But I would appreciate if you could show me how to make the camera works. Could you visit my question on :  http://stackoverflow.com/q/40659198/2135363 .. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use [MediaDevices.enumerateDevices()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices) to determine back camera:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(function(devices) {
  var cameras = [];
  devices.forEach(function(device) {
    'videoinput' === device.kind && cameras.push(device.deviceId);
  });
  // On my devices:
  // - cameras[0] - front camera;
  // - cameras[1] - back camera;
  var constraints = {video: {deviceId: {exact: cameras[1]}}};
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {
    // Do something with stream.
  });
});
```

Also please take a look to [MediaTrackConstraints.facingMode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints/facingMode).

Tested on following devices:

- Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1.1; **Pixel** Build/NOF27B; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Mobile Safari/537.36
- Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; **MotoG3** Build/MPI24.107-55-2; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Mobile Safari/537.36
- Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; **Moto G Play** Build/MPI24.241-2.35-1; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Mobile Safari/537.36
- Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; **ONE E1005** Build/MMB29M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Mobile Safari/537.36

Answer (score 0):

I have defined ***toOpenBackCamera*** which determines if to open a back camera or front camera. You can connect your own logic to this variable.

```
let backVideoDesc = {
  facingMode: "environment"
}

let frontVideoDesc = {
  facingMode: "user"
}

let toOpenBackCamera = true;

navigator.getUserMedia({
   audio: false,
   video: toOpenBackCamera ? backVideoDesc : frontVideoDesc
});
```

I hope this will help someone.
Source: [How To Change to Back Camera in Webview (Android)](https://questnr.com/post/brijeshlakkad_i-have-defined-toopenback-which-6630058821523291228-09212)