# Camera allow doesn't work android webview

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, webview, camera

I am trying to create a `webview` app. I tried to add the access to manifest but it didn't change anything. On the chrome browser the camera works, I can't understand what should I do.

**1. This is the manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="i.astiapp.astiappadmindev">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="true" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- My Location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".MainActivity">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /></intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**2. Main Activity**

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.PermissionRequest;

import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyWebChromeClient.ProgressListener{
    private ProgressBar chromeProgressBar;
    WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        //chromeProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarChrome);
        //Settings
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();

        myWebView.getSettings().setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.NORMAL);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        }

        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

        //webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        //inizialize client

        //load website by URL

        myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.voyage-app.eu/asti-app/admin/index.php");
        //register token for notification

        // this.onStart();
        chromeProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            // Grant permissions for cam

            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    request.grant(request.getResources());
                }
            }
          });

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                chromeProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                chromeProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
           });
       }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateProgress(int progressValue) {
        chromeProgressBar.setProgress(progressValue);
        if (progressValue == 100) {
            chromeProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public class WebViewController extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if(myWebView.canGoBack())
            myWebView.goBack();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

I don't think I should post the `PHP` file since on the chrome browser the page works. It happens like this:

- You enter the page
- Chrome browers asks you to give you the permission to the camera
- The camera starts working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it. I had to add the permession to the code:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        int hasCameraPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

        List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (hasCameraPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissions.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

        }
        if (!permissions.isEmpty()) {
            requestPermissions(permissions.toArray(new String[permissions.size()]), 111);
        }
    }
```

But for this to work I had to add the manifest file too:

```
import android.Manifest;
```

Comment: Can you help me with this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63695705/enable-input-file-camera-on-android-webview