# How to open webview links within app android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am facing an issue that when I click on any link in the webview it automatically opens the chrome browser and open the link there

I am pasting main avtivity class here.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
    private lateinit var webView: WebView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
        // Get the web view settings instance
        val settings = webView.settings

        // Enable java script in web view
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

        // Enable and setup web view cache
        settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true)
        settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT
        settings.setAppCachePath(cacheDir.path)


        // Enable zooming in web view
        settings.setSupportZoom(false)
        settings.builtInZoomControls = false
        settings.displayZoomControls = false

        // Zoom web view text
        settings.textZoom = 100

        // Enable disable images in web view
        settings.blockNetworkImage = false
        // Whether the WebView should load image resources
        settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true


        // More web view settings
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            settings.safeBrowsingEnabled = true  // api 26
        }
        //settings.pluginState = WebSettings.PluginState.ON
        settings.useWideViewPort = true
        settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
        settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        settings.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false


        // More optional settings, you can enable it by yourself
        settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true)
        settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
        settings.allowContentAccess = true
        settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true)
        settings.allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true
        settings.allowFileAccess = true

        // WebView settings
        webView.fitsSystemWindows = true


        /*
            if SDK version is greater of 19 then activate hardware acceleration
            otherwise activate software acceleration
        */
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)


        // Set web view chrome client
        webView.webChromeClient = object: WebChromeClient(){
            override fun onProgressChanged(view: WebView, newProgress: Int) {
                progress_bar.progress = newProgress

            }
        }
        webView.loadUrl(url);


        fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
            if (url.contains("stackoverflow.com")) {
                view.loadUrl(url)
            } else {
                val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
                startActivity(i)
            }
            return true
        }
    }


    // Method to show app exit dialog
    private fun showAppExitDialog() {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

        builder.setTitle("Please confirm")
        builder.setMessage("No back history found, want to exit the app?")
        builder.setCancelable(true)

        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ ->

            super@MainActivity.onBackPressed()
        }

        builder.setNegativeButton("No") { _, _ ->
            // Do something when want to stay in the app
            toast("thank you.")
        }

        // Create the alert dialog using alert dialog builder
        val dialog = builder.create()

        // Finally, display the dialog when user press back button
        dialog.show()
    }

}


fun Context.toast(message: String) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

when I click on link. chorme browser is opening. I am new in android development and not able to handel this situation. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out, I have replaced ChromeViewClient with internal WebViewClient

Reference: [How to load an URL inside a WebView using Android Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47872078/how-to-load-an-url-inside-a-webview-using-android-kotlin)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
    private lateinit var webView: WebView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
        // Get the web view settings instance
        val settings = webView.settings

        // Enable java script in web view
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

        // Enable and setup web view cache
        settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true)
        settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT
        settings.setAppCachePath(cacheDir.path)


        // Enable zooming in web view
        settings.setSupportZoom(false)
        settings.builtInZoomControls = false
        settings.displayZoomControls = false

        // Zoom web view text
        settings.textZoom = 100

        // Enable disable images in web view
        settings.blockNetworkImage = false
        // Whether the WebView should load image resources
        settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true


        // More web view settings
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            settings.safeBrowsingEnabled = true  // api 26
        }
        //settings.pluginState = WebSettings.PluginState.ON
        settings.useWideViewPort = true
        settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
        settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        settings.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false


        // More optional settings, you can enable it by yourself
        settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true)
        settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
        settings.allowContentAccess = true
        settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true)
        settings.allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true
        settings.allowFileAccess = true

        // WebView settings
        webView.fitsSystemWindows = true


        /*
            if SDK version is greater of 19 then activate hardware acceleration
            otherwise activate software acceleration
        */
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)


        // Set web view client
        webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
            view?.loadUrl(url)
            return true
            }
        }
        webView.loadUrl(url);


        fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
            if (url.contains("stackoverflow.com")) {
                view.loadUrl(url)
            } else {
                val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
                startActivity(i)
            }
            return true
        }
    }


    // Method to show app exit dialog
    private fun showAppExitDialog() {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

        builder.setTitle("Please confirm")
        builder.setMessage("No back history found, want to exit the app?")
        builder.setCancelable(true)

        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ ->

            super@MainActivity.onBackPressed()
        }

        builder.setNegativeButton("No") { _, _ ->
            // Do something when want to stay in the app
            toast("thank you.")
        }

        // Create the alert dialog using alert dialog builder
        val dialog = builder.create()

        // Finally, display the dialog when user press back button
        dialog.show()
    }

}


fun Context.toast(message: String) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method you need to use is called [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)).
What worked for me was to create simple MyWebViewClient class which inherits from WebViewClient and override the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method. Then just pass it to your WebView during setup.

```
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient

class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
        // Do not open new browser to load new link, load them in this webview
        return false
    }
}


// initalising webView
myWebView.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()
```

Comment: quite simple and effective