# How to get access android camera using jquery,html or php

Tags: php, android, jquery, html, android-webview

I want to do something like this.
https://pixlcore.com/demos/webcamjs/demos/basic.html

this is perfectly working in web browser.

but when i load this site on my android webview then it doesn't show anything.

can any one have idea to doing this task for any other way.

Anyone help me???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659198/how-to-access-the-camera-from-within-a-webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659198/how-to-access-the-camera-from-within-a-webview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the camera from within a Webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659198/how-to-access-the-camera-from-within-a-webview)