# Android - How to access camera using webview

Tags: java, android, html, webview, camera

I am trying to implement an app which loads a website that has html5 camera inside a Webview. I did many research based on it but couldn't achieve that. The website works perfectly inside the webview but the camera is not working. Even i have the required permission

Here's a url of a website which has camera on it,

https://davidwalsh.name/demo/camera.php

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I expect the camera working inside the webview but the camera is blank

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44398308/4079010

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work for me

Comment: why?? what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: The html5 camera is not working inside the webview

Comment: are you getting any error in native app or inside webview console ??

Comment: No brother i dont get any error! i am tryna load this link  https://davidwalsh.name/demo/camera.php in android webview. Except the camera in the url the rest works well.

Comment: @WalledhNaim There must be some error in the webview console.