# html camera video stream doesnt show in android webview

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have a website that I converted to an apk using android studio. The app works fine, however when i try to use a camera it shows this image:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSDv2.png)

The camera stream shows in the browser on my phone.
When i google about this the solutions are using old deprecated code from before androidx and dont work anymore.[I cant get this solution to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659198/how-to-access-the-camera-from-within-a-webview) How do I fix this?

```
mainactivity:
package name;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse = "show";
    private WebView webview ;
    private ProgressBar spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        webview = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        spinner = findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());

        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
        webview.loadUrl("url");


    }


    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView webview, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

            if (ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse.equals("show")) {
                webview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse = "hide";
            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (webview.canGoBack()) {
                        webview.goBack();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="name">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA2" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity main xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="name"> <WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:visibility="gone" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
android:textColor="#33b5e5"
android:textSize="50sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows. -->
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
    style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/black_overlay"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent">



</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying a `WebChromeClient` with `onPermissionRequest`

The following would grant permission for everything

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

   @Override
   public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
       request.grant(request.getResources());
   }

 });
```

Comment: It still shows the same play icon... Got any other ideas?

Comment: It might need the camera permission adding into the app and requesting to the user