# Give Webview Camera Permissions

Tags: java, android, webview, permissions, camera

New to Android and just looking to have a webview that has access to the camera. I have seen many discussions about this but can't make it work for my code. When I go to a webpage that has access to camera, it just says - no camera.

```
    package com.company.test;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.PermissionRequest;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.Manifest;

import java.util.Objects;

public class ThirdActivity<Webview> extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView1;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

        WebView webView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        webView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView1.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView1.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);

        webView1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webView1.loadUrl("https://yahoo.com");

    }

}
```

My Android Manifest file is like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.test">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name="com.company.test.ThirdActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.company.test.SecondActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.company.test.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIDEO_CAPTURE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUDIO_CAPTURE" />

</manifest>
```

Any help appreciated - use small words only, I'm new to this!

Another solution ([How to access the camera from within a Webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659198/how-to-access-the-camera-from-within-a-webview)) suggests this code:

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

   

    @Override
       public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
             request.grant(request.getResources());
          }
       }
    
     });
```

Now this seems to be what I need but I don't know how to include that in my code without generating errors. Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems like it does answer my question but I don't know where to put it in my code without getting errors. Any help?

Comment: maybe post these "errors"? are your app have granted this permissions in own Settings, are you asking for it e.g. in [Runtime permission dialog](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)